# Make a fixed size UIView, like UISwitch (using IBDesignable)

Tags: ios, uiview, resize, ibdesignable

When I'm using [this guide](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6) to create a view that is designed in a XIB, reusable from within a storyboard using the IBDesignable attribute on my UIView subclass, how do I make it have a fixed size, and have its resizing behavior match that of a view like UISwitch?

With "resizing behavior" I also mean while designing in interface builder.

Answer (score 12):

You could override `intrinsicContentSize()` in your `UIView` subclass.
Then you won't need to supply height and width constraints in the interface builder.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

If you only want to supply one of the dimensions, you can use `UIView.noIntrinsicMetric` instead of a value.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: Just an aside: IB doesn't seem to render the size correctly unless you put position constraints on the view. This tripped me up at first.

Comment: FYI: In Swift 3, Xcode shows the signature as `override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { }`